# How to show $n$ is a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $a$ and $n$ be integers greater than 1. Suppose that $a^n-1$ is a prime. Show that $a=2$ and $n$ is a prime. What can you say about primes of the form $2^n+1$?

By $a^n-1=(a-1)(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^n) $ I deduce $a-1=1 \to a=2 $. However I find it difficult to deduce $n$ is a prime.
Could somebody help please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: Suppose $n$ is not prime, i.e. $n = bc$ for some integers $b,c \ge 2$.

Then, $a^n-1 = a^{bc}-1 = (a^b)^c-1$ where $a^b > 2$. Now use your previous deduction.

For the the last part "What can you say about primes of the form $2^n+1$?", suppose $n$ has an odd factor and use the identity $x^m+1 = (x+1)\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{m-1}(-1)^kx^k\right)$, which holds for odd integers $m$.

Comment: For the last part I showed $n$ cannot have odd factor, and hence $n$ must have even factors only. I can see that $n=2$ is valid and so is $n=2 \times 2 = 4$. What else could I say?

Comment: If $n$ has only even factors, what does the prime factorization of $n$ look like?

Comment: Oh I see. $2^n+1=2^{2^k}+1$ for integer $k$, which is fermat number. Thank you very much!